# JavaScript variable declaration

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between following types of var declaration in JavaScript?

```
$x

var x

var $x
```

Answer (score 7):

$x and x are simply two different variable names.  Like `var x` and `var y`.  Simply using $x is an implied declaration, except that if $x exists in a higher scope, you'll use it.  declaring `var $x` sets up a new $x in the current scope which avoids conflicts with any other $x at a higher scope.

Answer (score 4):

No difference except for scope. `$x` is just a variable name like `x`. `var` creates variables in a local scope, otherwise they are global.

This has nothing to do with jQuery, really.

Comment: This answer may seem confusing given the current content of the question since there is no longer any tag or mention of jQuery. To elaborate, `$x` and `x` variable names are no more different than `xy` and `x`. However, `$` is sometimes used at the beginning of variable names by convention to indicate that the variable stores a reference to a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) object.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `$x` without declaring it, you are implicitly creating a global variable called `$x`. `var x` and `var $x` each create a variable in whatever function (or global scope) you're in, called `x` and `$x`, respectively. Neither has anything to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. I find it good practice, however, to precede variable names with a $ if it returns a jQuery object and without if it returns a DOM object or other type (string, etc.)

The term 'var' is useful for determining scope. Always use 'var' on first declaration, or on anytime you need a variable to be local in scope.